# Arriving at Newark from Europe, have ESTA, how long should it take to go through immigration and customs?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airport-transfer, ewr, new-jersey

I'll arrive at EWR on a Sunday at 12:30 and I'll have to book [a shuttle transportation](https://www.etsairportshuttle.com/) to my hotel.

At what time should I book the pick up ?

One hour is probably too short, especially if my flight is slightly delayed. Would 2 hours be OK?

I'll arrive from Belgium with an ESTA (visa waiver), a checked-in luggage and nothing to declare at the customs.

Comment: For historical wait times at the airport see http://awt.cbp.gov/. If you have previously entered the United States on the same passport, you may use the Automatic Passport Control terminals instead, which can cut your wait time down to a few minutes: http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc

Comment: Where is the hotel?

Comment: @Calchas I didn't know I don't have to register for APC. That will probably be the easiest and fastest way then. I guess I should fill the paper custom form just in case.

Comment: @Karlson New Brunswick, NJ. I have no idea if there are other (cheap) ways to get there. The shuttle is 29$.

Comment: @CedricH. There is a train that goes to New Brunswick but depending on where the hotel is in relation to the train station you may have to take a cab.

Comment: @Karlson It's the Hilton East Brunswick, so quite far from the train station apparently. I'll just be sure I have enough time to clear immigration at EWR, eat there if it is fast and then take the shuttle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Immigration and Customs is not easy to judge in the US. It all depends on flight arrival time, number of immigration staff on desks, any delays experienced to all incoming flights, if you get of the plane first or last, number of people to process, types of visas etc etc. In my experience I have waited between 30 minutes in line and 3 hours in line.

If I were in your situation then I would either be conservative with the shuttle booking and go for 2 -3 hours plus, or use the train from Newark to Penn and make my own way to the hotel.

Answer (score 3):

In actuality given where you are going there are public transit options available but again depends on the time of the day.

You can take a train from [Newark Airport to New Brunswick and then take 815/818](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Newark+Liberty+International+Airport,+Brewster+Road,+Newark,+NJ/Hilton+East+Brunswick,+Tower+Center+Boulevard,+East+Brunswick,+NJ/@40.5529675,-74.4545024,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c252e1c5ec0cef:0xb3f3b437c5d7f286!2m2!1d-74.174462!2d40.689531!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c3c621c111af0f:0xf6a3d20dff5c4484!2m2!1d-74.408729!2d40.480124!3e3) bus to get to the Hilton East Brunswick, so in this case the amount of time you spend in border control and customs won't really matter.